# ASP.NET Core 1.0, Linux, NGINX, Error -1 EPERM operation not permitted

Tags: linux, asp.net-core-1.0

I have ASP.NET Core 1.0 site.

My Program.cs file:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace A2Site
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://unix:/home/xubuntusall/MyPrograms/site/kestrel.sock")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I publish my site and copy to linux.

In linux terminal:

```
xubuntusall@PCXubuntuSall:~/MyPrograms/site$ dotnet ./A2Site.dll
dbug: Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection[3]
      Opening connection to database 'karpova' on server 'tcp://194.58.246.16:5432'.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory[1]
      Executed DbCommand (996ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT CASE
          WHEN EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM "Pages" AS "p")
          THEN TRUE::bool ELSE FALSE::bool
      END
dbug: Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection[4]
      Closing connection to database 'karpova' on server 'tcp://194.58.246.16:5432'.

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error -1 EPERM operation not permitted) ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.UvException: Error -1 EPERM operation not permitted
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Networking.Libuv.Check(Int32 statusCode)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.PipeListener.CreateListenSocket()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Listener.<>c.<StartAsync>b__6_0(Object state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelEngine.CreateServer(ServerAddress address)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer.Start[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at A2Site.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I remove the line

".UseUrls("http://unix:/home/xubuntusall/MyPrograms/site/kestrel.sock")"

from Program.cs, the site will work well, but I'm trying to run nginx + kestrel.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I moved the site from '/home/xubuntusall/MyPrograms/site/' to '/usr/site/' (and changed UseUrls) and it works.